# Is one allowed to wash and then wear shoes during the nine days

Tags: nine-days, shoes

I have a pair of shoes that I want to clean, (not just wipe down but put in the washing machine). I know this shouldn't be done for clothes but how about shoes?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Consider rephrasing this to make it more general e.g. "Is it permissible" rather than "can I".

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya. Please note that this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends. For a definitive ruling, please contact your rabbi. You might also want to see "[Why is it necessary to ask a rabbi?](//judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9146)" for more info. We hope to see you around!

Comment: Although this seems daft in retrospect, I though the question was about bathing and then putting on shoes. Maybe it should be changed from "wash and then wear shoes" to "wash shoes and then wear them."

Answer (score 1):

Probably not based on the halacha that allows applying polish if the shoe color has faded but does not permit shining.  This may be helpful  http://halachahbyemail.blogspot.com/2012/07/polishing-shoes-during-nine-days.html

Answer (score -2):

If it is not a cloth-like material, it wouldn't be considered "kibus". If you can wash your dishes, you can wash your shoes.

Comment: Is leather cloth like? Many shoes are made from cotton, leather and other regular clothing materials. I've never seen porcelain shoes. (I've seen wooden shoes.)

Comment: Leather is not cloth like enough to be considered kibus with just rinsing. Only scrubbing would be kibus by leather.

Comment: So scrubbing shoes is prohibited in the nine days?

Comment: @DoubleAA, I've seen porcelain shoes, but they weren't intended for wearing.

Comment: This answer could do with citations for its claims.